# If $f(x)=\int\frac{4(1-x^2)}{x^4+6x^2+1}dx$ and $f(0)=\cot^{-1}(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2a-1-a^2}})$, then find the number of integral values of $f(x)$

Tags: integration

> If $f(x)=\int\dfrac{4(1-x^2)}{x^4+6x^2+1}dx$ and $f(0)=\cot^{-1}(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2a-1-a^2}})$ for $a\in\mathbb R$, then find the number of integral values that $f(x)$ can take.

$$f(x)=\int\frac{4(\frac1{x^2}-1)}{x^2+6+\frac1{x^2}}dx=I$$

Putting, $x+\frac1x=t\implies\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)dx=dt$ and $x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2=t^2$

$$I=-4\int\frac{dt}{t^2+4}=-2\tan^{-1}\frac t2+C$$

So, $f(x)=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)+C$

Now, $f(0)=-2\times\dfrac{\pi}2+C$. Instead of $\dfrac{\pi}2$, it can be any odd multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}2$?

After that how do we compare it with the given value of $f(0)$?

Comment: I'm confused since $2a-1-a^2$ is always nonpositive. Are you sure you have the problem transcribed correctly?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^+}\bigg[-2\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x})\bigg]=-\pi~~~$ while $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^-}\bigg[-2\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x})\bigg]=\pi$

Comment: @NinadMunshi As Asher mentioned in their now deleted answer, $a=1$ satisfies.

Comment: Then did you mean for some $a\in \Bbb{R}$ ? As written what you have is probably fine but I find it hard to distinguish between $a\in\Bbb{R}$ meaning the domain and the other meaning.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Actually, I have posted the question verbatim.

Comment: @Asher2211 Thanks for reminding in your now deleted answer that the range of $\tan^{-1}x$ is $[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$. So, we can't have $\frac{3\pi}2$, etc.

Comment: The range of $\arctan$ function is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. As only $a = 1$ works and you know $f(0)$, you get value of $C$. Taking $C = \frac{5 \pi}{4}$, $f(x) = - 2 \arctan (x + \frac{1}{x}) + \frac{5 \pi}{4}$.

Comment: @MathLover As pointed out by Asher above, shouldn't $C$ take both $\frac{5\pi}4$ and $\frac{-3\pi}4$?

Comment: @aarbee yes, I just took one example.

Comment: @MathLover ok, thanks. With $\frac{5\pi}4$, I am getting $f(x)$ can take values between $-\pi+\frac{5\pi}4$ and $\pi+\frac{5\pi}4$ i.e. $7$ integral values. With $\frac{-3\pi}4$, I am getting $6$ integral values. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your working, $f(x)=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)+C \tag1$

As $f(0)=\cot^{-1} \left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2a-1-a^2}}\right)$, $f(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ as $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2a-1-a^2}})$ is real only for $a = 1$.

Now using $(1)$,

$C = -\frac{3 \pi}{4}~$ from the left and
$~C = \frac{5 \pi}{4}$ from the right

So we seek integer values of $f(x)$ such that,

For $x \gt 0$,

$f(x)=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}\right) + \frac{5 \pi}{4} \tag2$

For $x \lt 0$,
$f(x)=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}\right) - \frac{3\pi}{4} \tag3$

Note that $\frac{1}{2} |x + \frac{1}{x}| \geq 1$.

So range of $f(x)$ for $(2)$ can be written as,

$\frac{\pi}{4} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$

We can now easily count the number of integer solutions. Similarly check integer solutions for $(3)$.

Comment: Hi. I didn't understand how you calculated the range of $f(x)$, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @aarbee is it clear why $\frac{1}{2} |x+\frac{1}{x}| \geq 1$? Then for positive $x$, $\arctan \frac{x^2+1}{2x} \geq \frac{\pi}{4}$, right?

Comment: For positive $x$, $-2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}\right) + \frac{5 \pi}{4}$ is min when $\arctan$ function is $\pi/2$ and is max when $\arctan$ function is $\pi/4$

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. For $\frac{5\pi}4$, I am getting $4$ integral values. I'll now check for $-\frac{3\pi}4$.

Comment: For $-\frac{3\pi}4$, we are getting $3$ integral values?

Comment: @aarbee pls give me a few mins. I am checking something on this.

Comment: @aarbee I made a correction. As we have extended discussion in comments warning, we can discuss further in chat. With the correction, there are two integer solutions to $(2)$ and one solution to $(3)$.

Comment: Got it now, thank you very much.